# Encoding in python3 and python2.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, character-encoding

well i started doing some CTFs recently and i found this one that bringed me  to read a bit about encoding strings .
Well the cipher is : êööòõ¼±±åñæçòçð°ëñ±ðëåîçø´²±è÷îî±øûÛÓüÉ± 
and the hint says it's an URL , so it's obv that the cipher starts with the char 'h' 
i was trying to do have a look in Python3.7 and 2.7 
i started doing see the chr(ê) in 3.7 i had 234 as return result 
and in 2.7 i had 195 
while reading some articles , even the one of Stackoverflow's owner I did understand that the common encoding now is UTF-8 to solve the issue of the text above 127 , so I went looking to UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters and i found that 'ê' is encoded as U+00EB (AKA 195 171) in 2 bytes (Logical because it's above 127) 
and now I'm really lost , from where did the 234 came from ? 
and can you give me more information about encoding or articles to read ? i'm really lost.

Comment: In python 2.7, try `urllib.quote('ê')` (you need to `import urllib` before) and see where it gets you. You can also look in SO for `urllib`, `encoding`, `url` combinations. good luck.